# Django-registration not registering

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I followed this [guide](http://johnparsons.net/index.php/2013/06/28/creating-profiles-with-django-registration/) to extend registration in Django and it all seemed working until I clicked register and nothing happens. I checked in the command line with `sql` and table exists as per specification, however when I try to view items with `UserProfile.objects.all()` it returns empty list. Seems like nothing is getting sent anywhere upon form submission.

I get no errors, so bit confused on what is the issue.

**models.py**

```
def user_registered_callback(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
    profile = UserProfile(user = user)
    profile.first_name = str(request.POST["first_name"])
    profile.last_name = str(request.POST["last_name"])
    profile.city = str(request.POST["city"])
    profile.country = str(request.POST["country"])
    profile.save()

user_registered.connect(user_registered_callback)
```

**forms.py**

```
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm

class CustomRegistrationForms(RegistrationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(label ="First Name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(label ="Last Name")
    city = forms.CharField(label ="City")
    country = forms.CharField(label ="Country")
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class = CustomRegistrationForms), 
    name = 'registration_register', kwargs=dict(extra_context={'next_page': '/services/'})),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls'))
  ) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**registration_form.html**

```
<form method="post" action="" class="wide">
{% csrf_token %}

  ..sample form
  <label for="id_username">Username:</label>
  {% if form.username.errors %}
    <p class="errors">{{ form.username.errors.as_text }}</p>
  {% endif %}
  {{ form.username }}
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" value="Register"></input>                                           
</form>
```

Comment: Your action in form is empty, it is indeed not sent anywhere

Comment: Suggestion on what and where to send? I kinda logically figured something is wrong with the submission as all other parts I ironed out.

Comment: By adding `accounts/register/` to `action` in `form` tag it errors out with trying to find URL `http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/register/accounts/register/`

Comment: @Lukasz the first slash was missing, therefore was relative to itself as origin and resulted in /accounts/register/accounts/register.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove action from form tag completely. This will result in sending the form request as HTTP-POST to itself, in this case "/accounts/register". But this is not your main problem.

According to the documentation (https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/forms.html) after reading I'm pretty sure you are missing the fields required by registration.forms.RegistrationForm which you are subclassing. The backend will take care of these and reject the given values. Because you are only showing username and its errors in your template the other validation errors will never show up.

Add the required fields to your form and try again. You may want to simply render it through

```
{{ form.as_p }}
```

Comment: no luck, removed `action` so now it is `<form method="post" class="wide">` and still same issue. Console is showing `"POST /accounts/register/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8210` so no error codes or anything

Comment: So some progress! with using form.as_p now I get
`[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it` which means there is something happening unlike before. I found couple reasons online, something about a port but not too sure what are fixes for such, thoughts?

Comment: seems I have to configure email server for the registration, however I did set it up as `simple` and it shouldnt require email verification